# Launch two coroutines and wait for single result

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I wonder if there is any other way to launch two coroutines and return result from faster one.
I've done it using channelFlow, but I think there might be some other solution.

```
suspend fun execute(): Result {
    return channelFlow {
        listOf(
            coroutineScope.async { send(firstCourotine()) },
            coroutineScope.async { send(secondCourotine()) }
        ).awaitAll()
    }.first().also { cancel() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `select` expression for that, making `execute` a `CoroutineScope` extension function:

```
suspend fun CoroutineScope.execute(): Result {
    val list = listOf(
        async { firstCourotine() },
        async { secondCourotine() }
    )

    return select {
        list.forEach {
            it.onAwait { answer ->
                answer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should call `execute` in a scope that you can cancel in order to stop all its active coroutines as soon as you receive the result:

```
...
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
val result = scope.async {
    val res = execute()
    coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    res
}.await()
//Do something with 'result' here
...
```

NOTE: `select` expression is in experimental state.

You can find `select` expression official documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html).